# PageViewController embedded in other PageViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have got a `PageViewController` that I created in a `ViewController`, as you can see next:

**MainViewController (viewDidLoad())**

```
self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
let initialViewController : UIViewController! = viewControllerArray.objectAtIndex(self.currentPageIndex) as! UIViewController
let viewControllers: NSArray? = NSArray(objects: initialViewController)

pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated:true, completion: nil)

self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    self.syncScrollView()
```

And everything is all right. This `viewController` catch the event on the method

```
func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
```

My problem is that one of the pages of this pageViewController has other UIPageViewController inside, with other UIViewController associated. The way I am creating the other UIPageViewController is:

**SecondViewController (`viewDidLoad()`)**

```
self.pageNoticiaViewcontroller = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Vertical, options: nil)
            self.pageNoticiaViewcontroller.didMoveToParentViewController(self);
    self.pageNoticiaViewcontroller.dataSource = self;
    self.pageNoticiaViewcontroller.delegate = self;

    let startVC = self.getControllerAtIndex(0) as InicioIndividualUIViewController;

    let viewControllers = NSArray(object:  startVC);

    self.pageNoticiaViewcontroller.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil);

    self.pageNoticiaViewcontroller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 40);

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageNoticiaViewcontroller);
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageNoticiaViewcontroller.view);
```

The problem is:

The second PageViewController (`pageNoticiaViewController`) **doesn't call to the method `presentationCountForPageViewController`** but it calls to the method `presentationCountForPageViewController` **of the parent**

How can I do that second `PageViewController` calls to method `presentationConuntForPageViewController` of the second UIViewController, insetead of call to method of the parent? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

i think you have to try like this :

```
self.pageViewController.view.tag=0 

self.pageNoticiaViewcontroller.view.tag=1
```

and put condition in datasource and delegate method like

example:

```
 func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
{  

if pageController.view.tag == 0
{
     return  yourcount // here self.pageViewController count
}
else
  {
     return  yourcount  // here self.pageNoticiaViewcontroller count
  }
}
```